# How to convert a vector to an array of a typdef type

Tags: c++, arrays, file, vector

I have a typedef defined in a header file as:

```
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
```

And I have the following code:

```
BYTE rgbPlaintext[] = {0x00};
rgbPlaintext* = &vec[0];
```

`vec` is an array of `unsigned char` that is populated by a file (no issue there). My issue is, the above code does not build successfully, all it says is `syntax error : '='` at the line `rgbPlaintext* = &vec[0];`

How can I successfully point the array to the array that is in the vector that is of the underlying type of the typedef?

Thank you.

Comment: Stop using an array. `BYTE *rgbPlaintext = &vec[0];`

Comment: `rgbPlaintext` is an array, you can't make it point to another array. What do you want?

Comment: I need to have an array of BYTE so that I can pass it to methods that accept an input of BYTE[]

Comment: @ITWorker You can pass `&vec[0]` directly. Or copy the content from `vec` to `rgbPlaintext`, then pass `rgbPlaintext`.

Comment: @songyuanyao How do you copy from a vector to an array in this case, where the type is different even though the underlying types are the same (unsigned char)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is, the above code does not build successfully, all it says is `syntax error : '='` at the line `rgbPlaintext* = &vec[0];`

You get the error because the compiler expects a right hand argument to the multiplication operator but instead found `=` which is not a valid operand for the multiplication operator. I get the feeling that a multiplication was not your intention.

> How to convert a vector to an array of a typdef type

Vectors can not be converted to an array.

Perhaps you mean to copy the contents of the vector into an array. That's simple:

```
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), rgbPlaintext);
```

You need to be careful, however. If the array is smaller than the vector, then it will overflow and you get undefined behaviour.

> How can I successfully point the array to the array that is...

Arrays do not point anything and you can not make them point anything. Arrays *contain* objects.

In this case the array `rgbPlaintext` contains a single element with the value `0x00`. You can use the method I showed to copy contents of a vector to `rgbPlaintext`, but if the vector contains more than one element, the copy will overflow.

> How would one know the size of an array needed if the vector that the array is based off of is populated by a data file?

The size of a vector can be known using `std::vector::size()`. But the size can not be known at compile time, so if you intend to copy the contents to an array and cannot limit the maximum size, then you cannot use an automatically or statically allocated array. You can use a dynamically allocated array, and for that, I recommend using a `std::vector`.

Copying a vector to another is simple:

```
std::vector<BYTE> rgbPlaintext = vec;
```

This is OK as long as `BYTE` is the same type as `decltype(vec)::value_type`. It does not matter if one type is an alias of the other.

Comment: How would one know the size of an array needed if the vector that the array is based off of is populated by a data file?

Answer (score 0):

For the code:

rgbPlaintext* = &vec[0];  // vec is an array of unsigned char

The syntax is incorrect rgbPlaintext* as said in another post.

To do the following:

*How can I successfully point the array to the array that is in the vector that is of the underlying type of the typedef?*

I'm going to assume that what you are really saying that vec is a vector from std that contains arrays of unsigned char's.  If this is the case then I would do the following:

```
BYTE* rgbPlaintext = NULL;
rgbPlaintext = vec[0]; // any subscript of the list of arrays
cout << rgbPlainText[0] << endl; // return the first value at sub of array attained from vec
```

Here is small test program to clarify my understanding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    typedef unsigned char NBYTE;
    typedef vector<NBYTE*> TEST_ARRAYBYTE;

    NBYTE *rgbPlaintext = NULL;
    NBYTE testarray[] =  {'2', '1'};
    NBYTE testarray1[] =  {'1', '2'};

    TEST_ARRAYBYTE vec;
    vec.push_back(testarray);
    vec.push_back(testarray1);

    rgbPlaintext = vec[0];

    cout << rgbPlaintext[0] << endl;
    rgbPlaintext = vec[1];
    cout << rgbPlaintext[0] << endl;

}
```